# "Could not load file or assembly" error but I don't know which project is referencing this assembly with old number

Tags: .net, reference, .net-assembly

When I am launching my WPF application, I got the error "Could not load file or assembly 'ASSEMBLY_NAME, Version=0.4010.4609.26378, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='XXX' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)".

The ASSEMBLY_NAME is the name of one project, which is referenced by many other projects because it is a core. My WPF project is also referencing it, and some projects referencing ASSEMBLY_NAME are references of my WPF project. However, both WPF project and its references which are referencing ASSEMBLY_NAME, they all reference the version 0.4010.4610.xxxx. So even though I understand why this error happens--it's because an older version is the target however I only have newer version, I can't find out which project or part is referencing the version 0.4010.4609.xxxx. As I mentioned, the startup project, my WPF project is not. Could anyone tell me how to check who is referencing it? Thanks.

Comment: You might try using the [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.100).aspx) which may give more hints on this failure.

Comment: Thanks you @Damien_The_Unbeliever , it funny because I just learned Fuslogvw.exe last month in one problem and I thought "it's a great tool", but this time it didn't occur to me that I should use it again. As I commented on Daniel's answer, I found out it was because I was referencing a exe project. And in fact Fuslogvw points to the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the properties of each reference to ASSEMBLY_NAME and verify that the path you see is something like `ASSEMBLY_NAME\bin\Debug` and not `PROJECT_CONTAINING_THE_REFERENCE\bin\Debug`.

Alternatively you can delete all your `bin` and `obj` folders in the projects and do a Rebuild All. One of your projects should fail building. That's the one with the wrong reference.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, It is neat. I went to the second method and it said "Cannot find library AA.exe". This AA.exe is an old WPF project, I am making a new project to replace it so I wanted to use some classes of it. But I guess it's never a good idea to reference an exe file. And in long term perspective, we will get rid of AA  anyway. So I just copied those classes I need to my new WPF project(or probably make a new library in the future). And now it is working fine.